# Как выбрать блок с одинаковыми id?

Tags: jquery, php

Всем привет. Да я прочитал что использовать одинаковые id нельзя. Но все же объясню суть своей задачи.

У меня генерируется 10, 20, 30 блоков с одинаковым id(можно сделать с классом). Хочу что бы при нажатии на рядом кнопочку открывался нужный блок. В моей случае открывается только первым. А если тоже самое написать через сlass, то открываются сразу все. Как сделать что бы выбирал именно тот блок который мне нужен.? Ниже привожу код

HTML

```
 <div class="shop_info">Показать</div> 
 <div class="show_shop_info">Cдесь информация которая должна показываться</div>

 <div class="shop_info">Показать</div> 
 <div class="show_shop_info">Cдесь информация которая должна показываться1</div>

 <div class="shop_info">Показать</div> 
 <div class="show_shop_info">Cдесь информация которая должна показываться2</div>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var i=0;
    $('.shop_info').click(function() {
        if (i==0) {
                $('.show_shop_info').slideToggle('slow');
                $('.shop_info').text('Спрятать');
                i=1;
            } else {
        if (i==1) {
            $('.show_shop_info').slideToggle('slow');
            $('.shop_info').text('Показать');
            i=0;
        }
        }
      });

});
```

Comment: > Cдесь

**З**десь

внутри функций-обработчиков элемент, к которому относится событие, доступен как `this`. Это именно "сырой" элемент и для получения jQuery-объекта его надо создать:

    $('.shop_info').on('click', function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.text('Спрятать');
        $this.next('.show_shop_info').slideToggle('slow');
    });

Comment: Наверное цепочка методов выглядит проще:

    $(this).text('Спрятать').next().slideToggle('slow');

Comment: сколько можно повторять - один id на документ, уникальный. это как номер купюры, или пасспорта или другого **ид**ентификатора

Comment: ТЫ ГДЕ ТУТ ВИДИШЬ ID? тут все реализовывается через класс.

Comment: > У меня генерируется 10, 20, 30 блоков с одинаковым id

Comment: показывай так:

    $(this).next().slideToggle('slow');

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).on('click', '.shop_info', function () {
  var $this = $(this), $next = $this.next();
  $this.text($next.is(':visible') ? "Показать" : "Скрыть");
  $next.toggle('slow')
});
```

```css
.shop_info {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.show_shop_info {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="shop_info">Показать</div> 
<div class="show_shop_info">Здесь информация которая должна показываться</div>

<div class="shop_info">Показать</div> 
<div class="show_shop_info">Здесь информация которая должна показываться1</div>

<div class="shop_info">Показать</div> 
<div class="show_shop_info">Здесь информация которая должна показываться2</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <style type="text/css">
    .hide
        {
           display: none;
        }
 </style>

<div id="btn_info_1">Показать</div> 
<div id="block_info_1 hide">Cдесь информация которая должна показываться</div>

<div id="btn_info_2">Показать</div> 
<div id="block_info_2 hide">Cдесь информация которая должна показываться</div>

<div id="btn_info_3">Показать</div> 
<div id="block_info_3 hide">Cдесь информация которая должна показываться</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
      $('[id ^= "btn_info"]').click(function(){
         var id = $(this).attr('id');
         var number_id = id.split('_');
         number_id = number_id[number_id.length -1];
         $('#block_info_'+ number_id).removeClass('hide');
      });
   });
</script>
```

Comment: @ruslik, эт какой индус вас на такое подталкнул? ![alt text][1]


  [1]: http://i.imgur.com/e5w3cNG.gif

Comment: Deonis
а что не так?

Comment: @ruslik, как бы вам это сказать?... Говорят (*хотя это может и слухи*), что в индии программистам платят или платили за количество написанного кода. То есть: "**Чем больше кода, тем больше риса на обед**". Поэтому, ничего удивительного роботодатель не видел в "шедеврах" такого типа:

    var x = false;
    if (x === 0) {
       // Do 1....
    } else if (x != 0) {    
       // Do 2.....
    } else {
        if(typeof x == 'boolean' && (x === false || !x)){
           // А вот здесь чистые деньги :)
        }
    }

Ваше решение на поставленную задачу - где-то на грани этого.

Comment: Да я понял, спасибо за совет, учимся, но есть 3 но: 
Первое, это то, что мой код будет работать если изменить структуру документа, добавить например между парой блоков еще один блок или вообще раскинуть блоки по разным местам, а во вторых если id измениться допустим с block_info_1 на info_1, то нужно будет изменить только id.
Ну а в третьих индусы не самые глупые в программировании