# Jquery нажатие на элементы с одинаковым тегом

Tags: jquery

Есть форма с множеством кнопок. Все кнопки имеют одинаковый `id`. Как сделать так,  чтобы при нажатии любой из кнопок происходило событие?

```
$('#select').click(function(event) {
    alert(1);
});
```

Делаю так, но это не работает. Срабатывает только при нажатии по первому элементу с таким тегом.

Comment: Как насчет того, что повторяться ID не могут?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).on('click', '.shop_info', function () {
  alert(1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="shop_info">Показать</div> 
<div class="shop_info">Показать</div> 
<div class="shop_info">Показать</div>
```

[Ещё есть вариант с разными действиями при нажатии на разные блоки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/470612/211218)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('div #select').click(function() {
    alert(1);
});
```